# How to setup Socket.io server for Unity on Digital Ocean?

Tags: node.js, unity-game-engine, socket.io, digital-ocean

I want to setup Socket.io server for my Unity game. I created Digital Ocean account and I don't know what to do next. Have anyone done this before?

On localhost server works as fine as I can imagine :)

Comment: Your question seems to be about nodejs or am I wrong?

Comment: You are absolutely right :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned you created a Digital Ocean account, and I am assuming you are running a varient of Linux (Debian/Ubuntu). For the server, you are going to need to install Node.js and NPM so that you can fetch the socket.io library. For the distro-stable version:

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get install nodejs`
3. `sudo apt-get install npm`

From here, a tutorial/simple server can be found [here](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/). This tutorial is for building a socket.io server for a chat app, but you can tailor it to the needs for your game.

For your Unity game itself, I think what you are looking for is [socket.io-unity](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/socket.io-unity). This will allow your game to act as a socket.io client to communicate with your socket.io server running in Node.js.

Comment: The asset you provide is quite cheap, but there is a free one also available. It works, it is just a bit old and no longer maintained. Depending on the purpose, it may be enough.

Comment: @Everts I'm sorry I don't understand what you are saying. Depending on the needs of his game, the socket.io server is going to be configured differently than other people's. Also, I think socket.io-unity is an excellent solution, especially since it is regularly maintained. Socket.io is also regulary maintained. In fact, I have contributed to the project a couple weeks ago.

Comment: Oh, maybe I see what you are saying. socket.io-unity's most recent activity has been updating their README, but it should still be fine :)

Comment: Yep I was talking Unity side, asset available on AssetStore but seems it has not been updated for 3 years... https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/network/socket-io-for-unity-21721

Comment: Cool. Thanks @Everts

Comment: Server and client code I did before I asked the question. But how to upload it to DigitalOcean? :P

Comment: You need to use SSH. Have you created a droplet in Digital Ocean?

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps simply:

1. Make Web socket server. Get its url
2. Use [**WebSocket Sharp**](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp) to communicate through websockets.

Comment: First you said to use WWW class then you edit for WebSocket. You should not try if you don't know. WebSocket is not socket.io. They do the same thing but they are not the same thing.On top of that he is asking for server side.

Comment: FYI! WebSocketSharp allow you communicate at client socket.

Comment: FYI, question is about socket.io.

Comment: Sorry i said Websocket sharp able to communicate with socket io at client side.

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan he is asking for a socket.io solution, not a websocket solution. Although socket.io uses websockets whenever it can, it often times uses XHR polling for the transport.